# I am not lost, but I can be found. What am I?

Tags: riddle

I am not lost, but I can be found.

If you have found me, then you should lose me again, in order to find me.

When you find me again it will surely be of benefit, similar to if you became more fit.

My composition of attributes is exactly that...

...found of the pages were: on a journey, five had me and five did not.
.

.

.

.

.

(this is my very first riddle, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, sorry for not rhyming)

Comment: Rhyming is definately optional. Some of the best riddles don't rhyme.

Comment: Reading the title, my first thought was "a Christian?" O.o  (Thinking Amazing Grace)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Thanks to OP's hint on Bible reference.  I'm not a Christian but hopefully the explanation are correct!

Is it

> Wisdom?

I am not lost, but I can be found.

> Blessed are those who find wisdom, those who gain understanding (Proverbs 3:13)

If you have found me, then you should lose me again, in order to find me.

> Do not deceive yourselves. If any of you think you are wise by the standards of this age, you should become "fools" so that you may become wise.  (Corinthians 3:18)

When you find me again it will surely be of benefit, similar to if you became more fit.

> Long life is in her right hand; in her left hand are riches and honor (Proverbs 3:16, but I don't get this one)

My composition of attributes is exactly that...
...found of the pages were: on a journey, five had me and five did not. .

> Five of them were foolish and five were wise (Mathew 25:2)

Comment: There I edited the answer, see if that works.  However I found that the Bible's line is just what I'm saying thou, but maybe in better grammer?

Comment: That's it! the "her" in "Long Life is in her right hand" is referring to wisdom. I was trying to say people who are more fit tend to live longer, but its apparent that was too ambiguous

Comment: @MrSudds Hey, I said it first! :-p Never mind, I have enough rep - Alex can get the checkmark. Good on you, Alex!

Comment: Hehe indeed I couldn't get the answer if I didnt' see yours @randal'thor =D

Comment: @randal'thor haha i tried to give you another hint w/o fully giving you the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This answer sounds wrong, but a certain important book tells us it could be right, so bear with me...

> LIFE?

*I am not lost, but I can be found.

If you have found me, then you should lose me again, in order to find me.*

> According to the [Gospel of Matthew](http://biblehub.com/matthew/16-25.htm) in the Bible, "Whoever finds their life will lose it, and whoever loses their life for my sake will find it."

*When you find me again it will surely be of benefit, similar to if you became more fit.*

> Going with this interpretation, you "find" your life again when you enter Heaven, which is surely a benefit. All your bodily weaknesses will have fallen away, as though you were suddenly more fit.

*My composition of attributes is exactly that...*

> The sum of all your attributes gives your life.

*...found of the pages were: on a journey, five had me and five did not.*

> This could be a reference to the Parable of the Ten Virgins (see [the Gospel of Matthew](http://biblehub.com/matthew/25-2.htm) again), in which "five of them were foolish and five were wise). So an alternative possibility would be WISDOM. Thanks to **Lawrence** for helping me with this line.

<sub><sub><sub>And who says I'm rude about Christianity now?!</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: A possible literary reference to the last part of your answer: Matthew 25.

Comment: @Lawrence Thanks! I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: that @Lawrence is a smart man :-) man, but don't be too narrowed, that book has many different books in it

Answer (score 3):

I am not lost, but I can be found.

> Hope

If you have found me, then you should lose me again, in order to find me.

> If you did find hope, unless you lose it, you are definitely not going to find it again.

When you find me again it will surely be of benefit, similar to if you became more fit.

> If you do find hope, its definitely beneficial, as you recover from an hopeless illness

My composition of attributes is exactly that...

> I hope I will lose weight/ I will gain weight / I will be fairer / I will be stronger. Just wish, and hope for something getting better

...found of the pages were: on a journey, five had me and five did not.

> It's an old adage, five had hope and five don't.

Comment: that's on the right track, but the last line is eluding to something very specific

Answer (score 1):

I am not lost, but I can be found.

> Your way

If you have found me, then you should lose me again, in order to find me.

> You have to get lost (lose one's way) in order to find it again.

When you find me again it will surely be of benefit, similar to if you became more fit.

> Definitely a benefit to know where you are going!

My composition of attributes is exactly that...

> Hmm, maybe it's weight?  No, it's way....

...found of the pages were: on a journey, five had me and five did not.

Comment: the last line references something very specific

Answer (score 0):

I think it is:

> Faith

I am not lost, but I can be found.

> You can find faith in anything (God, Higher Power, Universe, humanity, etc.)

If you have found me, then you should lose me again, in order to find me.

> Some people "lose" their faith, and some of those find it again.

When you find me again it will surely be of benefit, similar to if you became more fit.

> Most people agree having faith in something is a benefit.

My composition of attributes is exactly that...

> Faith is a composition, or perhaps is "found" by a composition of a lot of things. Experiences, miracles, evidence, lack of evidence, etc.

...found of the pages were: on a journey, five had me and five did not. .

> Referencing the ten virgins and the wedding feast. There was a journey to the feast. Five had "oil" which many believe represents faith, and five did not.

Comment: you're very close with the last line. you got what i was referencing but looked too specific and missed the context